# Coding Custom Likelihood Pymc3

Tags: python, statistics, bayesian, pymc3

I am struggling to implement a linear regression in pymc3 with a custom likelihood.

I previously posted this question on CrossValidated & it was recommended to post here as the question is more code orientated (closed post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/541261/custom-likelihood-regression-pymc3))

Suppose you have two independent variables x1, x2 and a target variable y, as well as an indicator variable called delta.

- When  delta is 0, the likelihood function is standard least squares
- When delta is 1, the likelihood function is the least squares contribution only when the target variable is greater than the prediction

[image]

Example snippet of observed data:

```
x_1  x_2     observed_target  
10    1   0   100              
20    2   0   50               
5    -1   1   200             
10   -2   1   100
```

Does anyone know how this can be implemented in pymc3? As a starting point...

```
model =  pm.Model()
with model as ttf_model:

  intercept = pm.Normal('param_intercept', mu=0, sd=5)
  beta_0 = pm.Normal('param_x1', mu=0, sd=5)
  beta_1 = pm.Normal('param_x2', mu=0, sd=5)
  std = pm.HalfNormal('param_std', beta = 0.5)

  x_1 = pm.Data('var_x1', df['x1'])
  x_2 = pm.Data('var_x2', df['x2'])

  mu = (intercept + beta_0*x_0 + beta_1*x_1)
```

Comment: I think the `switch` function will do that. Here is one example usage: https://discourse.pymc.io/t/sum-distributions-based-on-another-distribution/7976/2

Comment: Hmm - are you able to give an example of how the switch function can be used with a custom likelihood?

Comment: Silly question: how is delta any different than having a third independant variable x_3? Could you not get an accurate prediction using 3 independant variables?

Answer (score 2):

In case this is helpful, from reading the docs it looks like something along these lines might work, but I have not been able to test it and it was too long to pop into a comment.

```
model =  pm.Model()
with model as ttf_model:

  intercept = pm.Normal('param_intercept', mu=0, sd=5)
  beta_0 = pm.Normal('param_x1', mu=0, sd=5)
  beta_1 = pm.Normal('param_x2', mu=0, sd=5)
  std = pm.HalfNormal('param_std', beta = 0.5)

  x_1 = pm.Data('var_x1', df['x1'])
  x_2 = pm.Data('var_x2', df['x2'])
  delta = pm.Data('delta', df['delta'])  # Or whatever this column is
  target = pm.Data('target', df['observed_target'])
  
  ypred = (intercept + beta_0*x_0 + beta_1*x_1)  # Intermediate result
  target_ge_ypred = pm.math.ge(target, ypred)  # Compare target to intermediate result
  zero = pm.math.constant(0)  # Use this if delta==1 and target<ypred
  
  # EDIT: Check delta
  alternate = pm.math.switch(target_ge_ypred, ypred, zero)  # Alternative result
  mu = pm.math.switch(pm.math.eq(delta, zero), ypred, alternate)  # Actual result wanted?
```

Comment: I wonder if it will be helpful to define `ypred` using `pm.Deterministic`.  Also, instead of equating `alternate` to `zero` maybe it should be set to `target` (when `target_ge_ypred`); this might achieve the desired effect.